# Unable to remove file in c using threads

Tags: c, multithreading

Im making a server client system in C using sockets, in my main program of the server, I create multiple threads to have multiple access to the server.
I have a file where I store some informantion from the users, when the client disconects from the server, and before closing the thread I want to update the information on the file about that user, using a simple code of copying the file to a temporary file, deleting the main file and renaming the temporary file to the main file name. And I exit my thread.

Issue:
The program is not able to delete the main file.
But I tested it on the temporary file and it deletes.

I tested multiple things and Im not able to remove the main file, it is allways saying it is unable to delete it.

```
if (remove("ScoreBoard.txt") == 0)
    printf("Deleted successfully");
else
    printf("Unable to delete the file");

/* Rename temporary file as original file */
rename("replace.txt", "ScoreBoard.txt");
```

Comment: If only the `remove` function provided some way to tell why it had failed.

Comment: Use `perror` upon failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the file open in another thread? Depending on your platform, that might prevent you from deleting the file.

Comment: Never Mind you're right, I forgot to close the file in the main thread of the server and I That was causing it not to be able to remove.